# http redirect loop ,multilangual website

Tags: php, multilingual

I'm trying to make my site in two language, in English (en) and in Azerbaijani (az) 
I store the language in the $_SESSION variable, the default language is English and I keep the language files in web root and Azerbaijani in an az folder.

My problem is when the language is changed for example to az I redirect the user to `http://thephotofilm/az/......` and I dont want the users go to `http://thephotofilm.com/......` because the current language is az so I tried some ways but sometimes I have redirect loops and I can't figure it out

```
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if( isset($_SESSION['lang']) ) { 
    $lang=$_SESSION['lang'];
}

if( isset($_COOKIE['lang']) ) { 
    $lang=$_COOKIE['lang'];
}

if( $lang == "az" && strpos($request_uri,"/az/", 0) !== 0 ) {
    header("Location: /az".$request_uri);
}

if( $lang=="en" && strpos($request_uri,"/az/", 0) === 0 ) {
    header("Location: ".substr($request_uri, 3));
}
```

Comment: First of  all, format your code in a readable way, like I just did for you. Otherwise it's impossible to even start working with it.

Comment: There is something wrong with this: `http://thephotofilm/az/......`. You forgot the .com, right?

Comment: And try to make less spelling mistakes, corrected them for you.

Comment: domain is http://thephotofilm.com

Comment: Then why don't you correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the path in a variable for selected version.

For eg:

```
if(english)
    $base_url="http://thephotofilm.com/" // for English
else
    $base_url="http://thephotofilm.com/az" // for Azerbaijani
```

Then start each link with variable $base_url

Comment: i want to return to the previous page when language is changed

Comment: how or when do you change the language?

Comment: with changeLang.php I set session variable to en or az

Comment: you will get the current page by using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], and you can redirect to the page corresponding to the changed language

Comment: if HTTP_REFERER is like thephotofilm.com/az/messages and user changes the language to en i need to change the url to the thephotofilm.com/messages ,remove the az part from url is there a mothod or an easy way to remove this part i tried some ways its long and causes sometimes redirect loops

Comment: Can you use string replace method 
eg: 

$referer_url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if(strrpos($referer_url,  "thephotofilm.com/az/") == false)
 $new_url = str_replace("thephotofilm.com/","thephotofilm.com/az/",$referer_url);
else
 $new_url = str_replace("thephotofilm.com/az/","thephotofilm.com/",$referer_url);

header("location:".$new_url);

Comment: I used a mthod like that but sometimes redirect loops occurs